# groupby with a boolean array, like a.groupby([True, True])

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I once saw a code segment using groupby as follows

```
a.groupby([True]*len(a))
```

Here `a` is a dataframe. I do not understand what does this try to do? If a has two rows. Generally, it is `a.groupby([True, True])`

Comment: Looks like it is a groupby of all elements in dataframe treated as belonging to the same group. Without a context, it is hard to say why this person did it in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The groupby parameter must have a length equal to that of the dataframe which is the number of rows (if the parameter is a column name, then its that by default, its a list, it must have the same length). It can be a list of lists, where each sublist must again have the length equal to that of the Dataframe (number of rows)*

Taking a toy dataset -

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,2],[3,4,5]], columns=['A','B','C'])
print(a)
```

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  2
1  3  4  5
```

Using the groupby function you are able to get a grouper object -

> multiply, * operation on a list replicates it by the scaler
>
> So, [True]*len(a) is the same as [True, True]

```
grp = a.groupby([True]*len(a)) 
grp
```

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x109ceb780>
```

If you list out the groups you will only get a single group -

```
list(grp)
```

```
[(True,    A  B  C
  0  1  2  2
  1  3  4  5)]
```

Maybe the author of that code segment was trying to just create a single tuple?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I posted a related question regarding groupby, would you like to take a look at it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497901/pandas-groupby-result-using-different-combinations-of-boolean-array-as-keys

Comment: replied to that post as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `groupby`, since the group key only have one unique `True`.
For all the function apply after groupby in

```
a.groupby([True]*len(a))
```

Can be done without `groupby`